# Authenticity_token disappears if remote: true is used in forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am doing Rails 4 form with remote:true option. The problem is that my authenticity_token disappears when I use remote true. However I still can submit the form for input text, but when I upload file I get this error:

```html
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
```

I searched at StackOverflow and found this solution:

```html
# application_controller.rb
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, if: Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json' }
```

But this way my form is being submitted as html form. Very strange, have no idea what to do.

EDIT: I added

```html
:authenticity_token => true
```

to my form_for, so now I have my authenticity_token set, but now as in case with adding protect_from_forgey with: :null_session, my form is submitted as general html.

Comment: Adding "authenticity_token: true" works with Rails 5 and Formtastic's `semantic_form_for` as well!

Answer (score -1):

Use this gem for upload file as remot true

```
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'
```

https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart